# Can someone explain this code for me please?

Tags: c++, iterator, compare

I am trying to understand what the iteraror compare?: in the code below does. Can someone please explain?
Thanks in advance

```
map<string,CvSVM>& classes_classifiers = predictor.getClassesClassifiers();
map<string,map<string,int> > confusion_matrix;
for (map<string,CvSVM>::iterator it = classes_classifiers.begin(); it != classes_classifiers.end(); ++it) {
    for (map<string,CvSVM>::iterator it1 = classes_classifiers.begin(); it1 != classes_classifiers.end(); ++it1) {
        string class1 = ((*it).first.compare("Foods")==0) ? "People" : (*it).first;
        string class2 = ((*it1).first.compare("Foods")==0) ? "People" :(*it1).first;
        confusion_matrix[class1][class2] = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's just "advance". Not "advanced".

Answer (score 0):

It could be written in a less obfuscated way as

```
it->first == "Foods" ? "People" : it->first;
```

since `string::compare` returns zero if the string compares equal to the argument.

`it->first` is the key from the key-value pair that the iterator refers to. So this gives the key, but changed to `"People"` if it was `"Foods"`.

Answer (score 0):

It's just [`std::string::compare`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/compare) used in a ternary operator.

`compare()` returns `0` if and only if the two strings are the same. Otherwise, it returns a positive or negative number depending on their relative lexicographical ordering.

Using `a.compare(b) == 0` is equivalent to `a == b`, but it can be slightly faster in this case as `b` is a string literal and using `==` would first convert it to a `std::string`, while `compare()` can interpret it directly.

As for the ternary operator, it does what it always did:

```
x = a ? b : c;
```

has the same functionality as this:

```
if (a) x = b;
else x =c;
```

except that it's an expression and not a statement. Which means it can be used to initialise a variable, as in your code.

Long story short, if the iterator points to a key `"Foods"`, the string will be set to `"People"`, otherwise it will be set to the key pointed to by the iterator.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation...and yes, the word i was looking for...Tenary operator

Answer (score 0):

There are two iterators one inside the other; it and the inner one it1. Inside the loops (at each iteration), class1 and class2 get some value according to the given criteria (if the element is "Food" class1 gets "People", otherwise gets the value of element). Then, confusion_matrix's corresponding element is filled with 0.